# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dt_user" , uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="user_no"), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="account")}
)

public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8149578944942492965L;
// Fields    

 private long id;
 private String userNo;
 private Set<UserRelative> userRelatives = new HashSet<UserRelative>(0);
// Constructors
/** default constructor */
public User() {
}
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user")
public Set<UserRelative> getUserRelatives() {
    return this.userRelatives;
}
}
```

above is user entity;below is another UserRelative entity：when want to getUserRelatives() the problem happens .

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dt_user_relative")
public class UserRelative  implements java.io.Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5035928604641787267L;
// Fields    

 private long id;
 private User user;
.....

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")

public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
.....
}
```

**my problem is that the error happens when i excute this code :how can i get getRelativeTickets() via userNo?**

```
userDAO.getUserByNo("10001148").getRelativeTickets().size();
```

---

```
public User getUserByNo(String userNo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String query = "from User t where t.userNo=?1";
    List<User> ls = this.findByQuery(query, userNo);
    if (ls.size() > 0)
        return ls.get(0);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its failing to lazily initialize the collection, because the Hibernate session is getting closed at the end of `getUserByNo` method - database connection is no longer available, and the object graph is detached. Now when you are calling `getRelativeTickets()` method, Hibernate can't fetch the association as the session is no longer available and Hibernate does not open a new connection (or session) implicitly to lazy-load the associations.

The recommended solution is to ensure that all the needed associations of the `User` are fully initialized before returning from `getUserByNo` method. In HQL, you can specify to eagerly fetch the association by using a `from` clause `fetch join`:

```
String query = "from User t left join fetch t.relativeTickets where t.userNo=?1";
```

This will return the `User` with the `relativeTickets` association fully initialized. With this, the initialization of the association happens in a single SQL statement, so it does not need to hit the DB again to initialize the association.